# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id_service' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, project

pls I need help :(
I'm trying to insert data into database but I got the following error :

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id_service' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `candidats` (`nom`, `prenom`, `email`, `adresse`, `date_naissance`, `telephone`, `cin`, `deleted`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (........)

I tried to make the 'id_sevice' nullabele and refresh the migrations but no result, also I don't want to give 'id_service' a default value knowing that it works when I gave it a default value

note that I'm working on two different tables on the same database
the first table is 'candidats' and the second is 'services' and the goal is to get the row id in the table 'services' and put it in the 'candidats' table

'id_service' must have a value and it can't be null or have a default value pls help me to solve this issue... :(

this is the candidat.php model:

```
class Candidat extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'candidats';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id_service',
        'demande',
        'nom',
        'prenom',
        'email',
        'adresse',
        'date_naissance',
        'telephone',
        'cin',
        'deleted'];

    public function candidatures()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Candidature::class,'demande');
    }



}
```

this is the Service.php model:

```
class Service extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'services';
    protected $fillable = [
        'nom_service',
        'nbr_poste_total',
        'nbr_poste_dispo'];

    public function candidatures()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Candidature::class)->orderBy('id', 'ASC');
    }
}
```

this is the CandidatController:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $new = 1;
        $request->validate([
            'nom' => 'required',
            'prenom' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'adresse' => 'required',
            'date_naissance' => 'required',
            'telephone'=> 'required',
            'cin' => 'required',
            'demande' => 'required',
            'service' => 'required',
            'doc' =>  "required|mimetypes:application/pdf|max:10000",
            'etat' => '',
            'description' => '',
            'deleted' => '' ,
//
        ]);
        $candidat=Candidat::select('id','cin')->get();
        if($candidat->count() == 0)
        {
            $data = new Candidat();
            $data->nom=$request->input('nom');
            $data->prenom=$request->input('prenom');
            $data->email=$request->input('email');
            $data->adresse=$request->input('adresse');
            $data->date_naissance=$request->input('date_naissance');
            $data->telephone=$request->input('telephone');
            $data->cin=$request->input('cin');
            $data->deleted="false";
            //$data->save();
            if(!$data->save())
            {
                return back()->with('error','Erreur! L\'enregistrement a échoué');
            }
        }

        else { //dump('not empty');
            foreach ($candidat as $candidat)
            {
                if ($candidat->cin == request('cin')) {
                    $new = 0;
                }
            }
            if($new == 1)
            {
                //dump('new');
                $data = new Candidat();
                //$data->id_service=$request->input('id');
                $data->nom=$request->input('nom');
                $data->prenom=$request->input('prenom');
                $data->email=$request->input('email');
                $data->adresse=$request->input('adresse');
                $data->date_naissance=$request->input('date_naissance');
                $data->telephone=$request->input('telephone');
                $data->cin=$request->input('cin');
                $data->deleted="false";
                //$data->save();
                if (!$data->save()) {
                    return back()->with('error', 'Erreur! L\'enregistrement a échoué');
                }
            }

            elseif ($new == 0) {
                //dump('old');
                $data = request()->validate([
                'nom' => '',
                'prenom' => '',
                'email' => '',
                'adresse' => '',
                'date_naissance' => '',
                'telephone'=> '',
                'deleted'=> '',
            ]);
                    $cand = Candidat::where('cin',request('cin'))->first();
                    $cand = Candidat::find($cand->id);
                    /*  $cand->nom=$request->input('nom');
                      $cand->prenom=$request->input('prenom');
                      $cand->email=$request->input('email');
                      $cand->adresse=$request->input('adresse');
                      $cand->date_naissance=$request->input('date_naissance');
                      $cand->telephone=$request->input('telephone');
                      $cand->cin=$request->input('cin');
                      $cand->deleted=$request->input('deleted');
                      */
                    if (!$cand->update($data))
                    {
                        return back()->with('error', 'Erreur! L\'enregistrement a échoué');
                    }

                    $candidat_nw = Candidat::orderby('created_at', 'DESC')->first();//->delete();
                    $prev_canditure = Candidature::where('candidat_id','=',$candidat->id)
                        ->orderby('created_at', 'DESC')->first();
                        if (!(empty($prev_candidature))){
                            $prev_canditure->etat = "Archivé";
                                $prev_canditure->save();

                                    }



                   // $prev_canditure->etat = "Archivé";
                    //$prev_canditure->save();

                }

        }
```

Comment: _"and the goal is to [...] put it in the 'candidats' table"_ - then why does the column list of the INSERT statement you have shown us not contain `id_sevice` to begin with ...?

Comment: thanks for your response, but Idk  why it doesn't shown, knowing that 'id_service' is a column in the 'candidats' table and it's a foreign key that references to id in the 'services' table